# get height of an uiscrollview with autolayout

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, swift, autolayout, xcode6-beta6

I have build an uiscrollview with pure autolayout, so I don't use :

> [scrollView setContentSize:CGMakeSize(contentWidth,contentHeight)];

the problem is that now I need to get the contentSize.height of the uiScrollView, but with autoloayout I am getting 0.

I need to get the contentSize.height to zoom in the scrollView when the user double tap.

the code I want to use is this one :
[ZoomToPoint](https://github.com/aclissold/The-Oakland-Post/blob/f06d97a780535419ae86b5dfc7574b76fe1fb000/The%20Oakland%20Post/ZoomToPoint.swift)

Can you help me to use this code with autoLayout?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have enough information to have any clue why you're getting 0, that doesn't seem to be happening to either of the scroll views in the app I'm currently working on. Maybe your autolayout constraints aren't quite right? Autolayout + `UIScrollView`s aren't a very simple combination. I've found it easiest to place all views with a plain `UIView` "container," and place *that* within a scroll view.

But do you actually even need the contentSize.height? To me, it makes sense to just double the scale on a zoomed-out double tap and zoom back out to 100% on a zoomed-in double tap:

```
func doubleTapReceived(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if recognizer.state == .Ended {
        if photo.scrollView.zoomScale == 1.0 {
            let point = recognizer.locationOfTouch(0, inView: <one of your views>)
            <your scroll view>.zoomToPoint(point, withScale: 2.0, animated: true)
        } else {
            <your scroll view>.zoomToRect(photo.frame, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

No subclassing required.

[Here's](https://github.com/aclissold/The-Oakland-Post/blob/add82b29d97bcfac2c900d4f511b0f9b19263a19/The%20Oakland%20Post/EnlargedPhotoGestureRecognizers.swift#L49-L59) the analogous part of my code. Maybe try cloning my project and building it and seeing how it differs from what you have? You can get to that particular scroll view by going to the Photos tab and tapping one of the thumbnail images in the collection view.

Comment: In your code, in the zoomToPoint method, line 17, you have :         `height = (self.contentSize.height / self.zoomScale)` this line is always 0 in my case.

Comment: My only guess is that your autolayout constraints aren't set up correctly. [This](http://natashatherobot.com/ios-autolayout-scrollview/) is a good tutorial on how to use an intermediary container view, but I'm not entirely sure if that'll fix your issue or not.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `layoutSubviews` methods in the `UIScrollView` subclass if you are subclassing `UIScrollView` or otherwise you could use `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method in `UIViewController` to find the correct `contentSize` of the scrollView.

Comment: Hello, I have try
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
            println("viewDidLayoutSubviews scroll view: \(maScrollView.contentSize.height)")
        }

but the result is still

viewDidLayoutSubviews scroll view: 0.0